# What is Terraform apply waiting for when it says 'still creating...'?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, microk8s

I'm using Terraform with Microk8s on my laptop. This is in preparation for using Terraform for something larger scale so I'm checking it out. I have 11 services and they all start just fine (as reported by Lens). But the Terraform `apply` command I ran never completes... well it does eventually with a timeout. It keeps saying `... Still creating...` for 4 of the 11 services. The others seem to be no problem.
The 4 services in question are ones we haven't written in-house ie postgres, mongodb, mongoexpress, and nginx. They all have liveness probes on them and Kubernetes thinks they are running okay. What is Terraform looking for that I have missed?
Thanks for any help

Comment: What provider do you use ?

Comment: Microk8s on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

This was just me misreading the message. The problem was that the *service* was not being created. The pods were there (as shown by lens).
The reason the services were not there is that I was configuring 3 load balanced services, each of which needs an allocated IP address and I had only configured one ip address.